# Process frames of video from AVFoundation in multiple thread Swift

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I have an an app, where I get all the frames from camera using AVFoundation, and process using the code below. I was wondering if there is a way to make this part multi threaded, so it can run faster. Maybe putting each frame in a queue in one thread, another thread to process the queue, and one queue to show the output of each frame as the output? I don't know if this can be done, but this is because the processing of each frame might take more time to process, and the image freeze in the output as a result.

This is the code for CaptureManager class:

```
class CaptureManager: NSObject {
internal static let shared = CaptureManager()
weak var delegate: CaptureManagerDelegate?
var session: AVCaptureSession?
var isBackCamera = true

override init() {
    super.init()
    
    session = AVCaptureSession()
    session?.sessionPreset = .high
    //setup input
    var device =  AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: .back)
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    if let stringOne = defaults.string(forKey: defaultsKeys.rememberCamera) {
        if(stringOne != "back"){
            device =  AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: .front)
        }
    }else{
        defaults.set("back", forKey: defaultsKeys.rememberCamera)
    }
    if(device != nil){
        device?.set(frameRate: 30)
        let input = try! AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device!)
        session?.addInput(input)
        //setup output
        let output = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
        output.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true
        output.videoSettings = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as AnyHashable as! String: kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA]
        output.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
        session?.addOutput(output)
    }else{
        print("no camera")
    }
}

func startSession() {
    session?.startRunning()
}

func stopSession() {
    session?.stopRunning()
}
func switchCamera(){
        //Remove existing input
    guard let currentCameraInput: AVCaptureInput = session?.inputs.first else {
            return
        }

        //Indicate that some changes will be made to the session
    session?.beginConfiguration()
    session?.removeInput(currentCameraInput)
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    if let stringOne = defaults.string(forKey: defaultsKeys.rememberCamera) {
        if(stringOne == "back"){
            defaults.set("front", forKey: defaultsKeys.rememberCamera)
        }else{
            defaults.set("back", forKey: defaultsKeys.rememberCamera)
        }
    }
        //Get new input
        var newCamera: AVCaptureDevice! = nil
        if let input = currentCameraInput as? AVCaptureDeviceInput {
            if (input.device.position == .back) {
                newCamera = cameraWithPosition(position: .front)
            } else {
                newCamera = cameraWithPosition(position: .back)
            }
        }
    newCamera.set(frameRate: 30)

        //Add input to session
        var err: NSError?
        var newVideoInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput!
        do {
            newVideoInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: newCamera)
        } catch let err1 as NSError {
            err = err1
            newVideoInput = nil
        }

        if newVideoInput == nil || err != nil {
            print("Error creating capture device input: \(err?.localizedDescription)")
        } else {
            session?.addInput(newVideoInput)
        }
    isBackCamera.toggle()
        //Commit all the configuration changes at once
    session?.commitConfiguration()
    

}
func cameraWithPosition(position: AVCaptureDevice.Position) -> AVCaptureDevice? {
    let discoverySession = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: AVMediaType.video, position: .unspecified)
    for device in discoverySession.devices {
        if device.position == position {
            return device
        }
    }

    return nil
}


func getImageFromSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer) ->UIImage? {
    guard let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) else {
        return nil
    }
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, .readOnly)
    let baseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBuffer)
    let width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelBuffer)
    let height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBuffer)
    let bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(pixelBuffer)
    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedFirst.rawValue | CGBitmapInfo.byteOrder32Little.rawValue)
    guard let context = CGContext(data: baseAddress, width: width, height: height, bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo.rawValue) else {
        return nil
    }
    guard let cgImage = context.makeImage() else {
        return nil
    }
    var image: UIImage
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    if let stringOne = defaults.string(forKey: defaultsKeys.rememberCamera) {
        if(stringOne == "back"){
            image = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage, scale: 1, orientation:.right)
        }else{
            image = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage, scale: 1, orientation:.leftMirrored)
        }
    }else{
        image = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage, scale: 1, orientation:.right)
    }
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, .readOnly)
    return image
}
}
```

This is the extention to process the each frame:

```
extension CaptureManager: AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {
func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
    guard let outputImage = getImageFromSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer: sampleBuffer) else {
        return
    }
    delegate?.processCapturedImage(image: outputImage)
}
}
```

Process function:

```
extension ViewController: CaptureManagerDelegate {
func processCapturedImage(image: UIImage) {
    self.imageView.image = ...
    //process image
}
}
```

And this is how its called in the ViewController:

```
        CaptureManager.shared.startSession()
```

Answer (score 1):

I fear that your question has more *queue* mentioned than in code samples.. but you don't need to fear anymore, we got this!

Before we modify any code, let's agree on this; camera itself deserves to have its own thread. Not on `DispatchQueue.main`, never.

Let's create a queue for our camera, something like;

```
var ourCameraQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "our-camera-queue-label")
```

Then use this queue over all the code you shared and wrap all the code inside each function in this;

```
func oneOfTheFuncs() {
  ourCameraQueue.async {
    ...
  }
}
```

and this should make things tiny bit faster.

One note is that you might want to initialize *(or better inject but we will come that later, maybe..)* `ourCameraQueue` as a first thing in *init* method. After initialization, make sure to wrap all remaining code in init method into `ourCameraQueue.async {}` as well.

Also skip the `ViewController` on wrapping and then read about code injection, that will help you on the future of your journey on this implementation.